# Python Array - Element by Index

Tags: python

I'm looking for a Python function which returns the element of an array at the index i.

For example, if the function is search(i), and A=[1, 4, 5, 2, 6], A.search(3) will return 2.

After googling I couldn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: I think you want `A[3]`...

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is called [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__):

```
>>> A=[1, 4, 5, 2, 6]
>>> A.__getitem__(3)
2
>>>
```

It is the [special method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) that is called when you do:

```
A[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

So it's obviously A[3].

For people getting stuck on such a topic, the python documentation for [Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/) and [Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3.3/) are available, I suggest you read them thoroughly.